# Layouts (layout under layout)

Tags: android, xml, layout

i have a problem with layouts. I am creating my project and i need to have buttons under buttons, so i need to have layouts under layouts. First layout is done so i want to ask you, how i can have my layout and buttons under the previous, because my second layout is on my first layout.

**My xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#bbbbbb"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="430dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/winter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"


            android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:onClick="Winter"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:text="Зима"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Middle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:drawablePadding="-15sp"
            android:onClick="Middle"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:text="Весна/Осень"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Summer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:drawablePadding="-15sp"

            android:onClick="Summer"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:text="Лето"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mmer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:drawablePadding="-15sp"

            android:onClick="Summer"
            android:paddingTop="32sp"
            android:text="Лето"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the orientation of root LinearLaout from horizontal to Vertical
 or

1. Use ConstraintLayout as root layout.
2. Create 2 Layouts of your choice and views inside it(buttons)
3. Constraint those 2 layouts one after the other